# How to change the hidden status of a UIImage that is inside an Array in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, image, syntax, uiimage

I'm doing a test app for iPhone (Swift) where my objective is to show multiple images that are currently hidden in a determinate order each time a button is pressed. I thought that i could write:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var num = -1

    var array: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "card 1.jpeg")!, UIImage(named: "card 2.jpeg")!, UIImage(named: "card 3.jpeg")!]


    @IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {

        num += 1
        array[num].hidden = false

    }
}
```

However, "array[num].hidden = false" isn't possible. I want to keep it as simple as possible. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`UIImage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/) doesn't have the property hidden.

I think you want an array of image views.

```
@IBOutlet var imageView1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var imageView2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var imageView3: UIImageView!
var imageViews = [UIImageView]()
var num = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageViews = [imageView1, imageView2, imageView3]
}

func button(sender: AnyObject) {

    num += 1
    imageViews[num].hidden = false

}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

`UIImage` has no member hidden - you cannot set its viability(UIImage have no visual representation). `UIView` have a member hidden, so you may try to use a `UIImageView` and just change the `image` property.

I assume you use storyboards, so you should get a outlet to the `UIImageView` to be able to access it.